# Ubuntu 20.04 Honor Earbuds not seeing Bluetooth Headset!

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS operating system. My bluetooth headset (Honor Earbuds 2 Lite) is not connecting. I turn on Bluetooth, but the name of the headset I use there does not appear. There is a solution for Airpods, I tried it and it didn't work, what else should I do?

Comment: This is an English-only site. If you don't know English, you can use [google translate](https://translate.google.co.in/). Bu sadece İngilizce bir sitedir. İngilizce bilmiyorsanız [google translate kullanabilirsiniz](https://translate.google.co.in/).

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. Installing "Bluez" at my system fixed it.

Visit [this page](https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-bluetooth-in-linux/) for more information